# block specific external calls in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

There is one specific call in our WordPress / WooCommerce installation that is using a lot of resources.

I would like to block this specific call to

```
downloads.infusedaddons.com
```

I believe it is simply checking for plugin updates in a very inefficient way.

I found that with the line...

```
define('WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL', true);
```

... I could block all calls and with the line...

```
define('WP_ACCESSIBLE_HOSTS', 'site1.com, site2.com');
```

... I then could allow specific sites to be allowed.

But this approach is too restrictive for our installation. Honestly I don't exactly know all external services that need to be allowed with this configuration. I already brought the email service down for a few hours.

So the best solution would be for me to specifically block this one external call.

How can I do it?

Comment: Fork the plugin? Disable the call via a hook (if it's hooked into one)? There's no way to know without knowing more about the plugin

Comment: Very good ideas. Thanks mevius!

Comment: Instead of blocking all external url calls and whitelisting some afterwards. How can we block just 1 external call? I feel like there should only be a 1 line of code for this, not two. Can you point me towards any direction? @rnevius